# Full text index and set a column as an attribute in sphinx?

Tags: linux, indexing, sphinx

I am trying to full text search a column, but also be able to group by it. Does that mean it needs to be attribute? I want to still be able to search on the column though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need attribute to use group by in Sphinx. 
For example you could use crc32(text) of your text column. Like:

```
sql_query = select text, crc32(text) as text_crc from mytable
sql_attr_uint = text_crc
```

So, text will be used for full-text search and text_crc for group by.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sql_field_string` to make a column both a full-text field, and an attribute.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-field-string

Then you can query it, and sort/group by it.